# Spark cassandra update/upsert

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I want to do an update/upsert in cassandra using spark RDD, may I know how it is possible?

*Update employee set salary = '' where empId = ''*

Answer (score 1):

Just use `rdd.saveToCassandra()` with the columns to be updated/inserted

Comment: Thanks, i'm currently using saveToCassandra() for insert but I'm doing the find and update using 
rdd.repartition(24).map

How to do a where condition which doesn't have a key?

Comment: I think I now understand that we need create multiple columns as primary key and then do the saveToCassandra() stuff.